# Issue creating SamlResponse when following your example Idp code - within the LoginResponse method

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have created an IDP using the code contained within https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs

This is throwing an error when I attempt to bind the authNResponse using the following code:

```
var responsebinding = new Saml2PostBinding();
responsebinding.Bind(saml2AuthnResponse).XmlDocument.OuterXml;
```

This is the same code as within the PostContent method, but I've opted to use this code direct as I just needed the SamlResponse.

The error is:

**Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenWriteException**: 'IDX13129: The SAML2:AttributeStatement must contain at least one SAML2:Attribute.'

With the following abridged stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.WriteAttributeStatement(XmlWriter writer, Saml2AttributeStatement statement)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.WriteStatement(XmlWriter writer, Saml2Statement statement)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.WriteAssertion(XmlWriter writer, Saml2Assertion assertion)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(XmlWriter writer, SecurityToken securityToken)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Tokens.Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.ToXml()
```

I have used your example code almost exactly, so is there an issue within it, or am I missing something?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a deeper analysis and two possible solutions/workarounds.

The situation: creating a ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse for a ClaimsIdentity that has only one claim: the nameidentifier.
The relevant code snippet (not complete, just the part that is relevant, but the ITFoxttec samples have the full code)

```
var response = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);
response.ClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "someone@somewhere.com") });
response.NameId = new Saml2NameIdentifier(....etc...);
var token = response.CreateSecurityToken(appliesToAddress);
//so far all is well, but the problem has been sneakily introduced!
//which is why the next line will give the error: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenWriteException: 'IDX13129: The SAML2:AttributeStatement must contain at least one SAML2:Attribute

return binding.Bind(response).ToActionResult();
```

Explanation:

ITfoxtec code: The nameidentifier claim is is removed from the claims when the token is created. This makes senses as it is supposed to be in the NameId property. This remaining claims are set as Subject in the SecurityTokenDescriptor that is fed to the Saml2SecurityTokenHandler which is Microsoft code.

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor();
tokenDescriptor.Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.Where(c => c.Type != ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

The claims in this tokendescriptor then end up as Attributes in the AttributeStatement in the generated Saml2SecurityToken (via a Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokendescriptor) call).

**Unfortunately, if the nameidentifier was the only claim you had, then you end up with an AttributeStatement that has no Attributes**. And subsequently run into the problem when the binding.Bind(response) deep down the bowels does its XML thing..
Unless you are supposed to always have an AttributeStatement it looks to me like a bug / edge case in the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml library.

There are two solutions to solve it:

1. Prevent ending up with no claims: Simply add another claim to the identity, doesn't have to be email, can be anything:

   response.ClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("x", "y"))
2. After the CreateSecurityToken call but before the call to Bind, check if the AttributeStatement is empty and if so remove it. A quick and dirty example for that:

   var x = (Saml2AttributeStatement)token.Assertion.Statements.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(Saml2AttributeStatement));
   if (x?.Attributes.Count == 0)
   {
   token.Assertion.Statements.Remove(x);
   }

Personally, I prefer option 1, as it is generally safer to use and less code. Plus I'm sure there can always be 'something' to further attribute the identity with...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the part of adding claims to the token and creating the token?

```
saml2AuthnResponse.SessionIndex = sessionIndex;

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
saml2AuthnResponse.NameId = new Saml2NameIdentifier(claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(c => c.Value).Single(), NameIdentifierFormats.Persistent);
saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity = claimsIdentity;

var token = saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSecurityToken(relyingParty.Issuer, subjectConfirmationLifetime: 5, issuedTokenLifetime: 60);
```

https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L110

Comment: Thanks Anders, but it is that line of code which is causing this error. If I comment the token out, the binding works, but then I cannot verify the assertion.

Comment: I have found that you need both the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier and ClaimTypes.Email claims in order for the token to be generated successfully. This seemed pointless, as both are the same value (in my test) but the token seems to require this.

I am, however, having another issue trying to assert the Saml2Response that I've just created. I am using the exact same configuration for both (so same certificate) yet I'm getting the following exception:

ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Cryptography.InvalidSignatureException: 'Signature is invalid.'

Comment: I have followed the code with https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreFramework/Controllers/AuthController.cs successfully for assertions from OneLogin. When I debug with my own assertion, I can read the assertion using binding.ReadSamlResponse, but yet the binding.Unbind is throwing the certificate error.

Comment: have you tried running the identity Provider test code in relation to the Service Provider code? You'll see from my comment above that the SamlResponse that I made from the Idp test code cannot be asserted using the Sp test code. Thank you

Comment: Apologies @anders-revsgaard, I was using the SP config for my IDP, which clearly wasn't right. After I altered my Identity Provider's config to mirror your example settings, this allowed the login (from Idp) and assertion (from SP) to work. One thing to note though. In your sample code, the Idp is using the itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testidpcore_Certificate.pfx whereas the SP was using the itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebappcore_Certificate.pfx. While these seemed the same, both configs needed to be using the same cert file. At least, this was the case for my tests. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you need both the ClaimTypes.**NameIdentifier** and ClaimTypes.**Email** claims in order for the token to be generated successfully.